# How to properly use clearInterval in this function?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that sets a reminder to pop up on the screen, but the message wont go away. Am I using the clearInterval with react hooks correctly in this function?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      handleReminder(activeReminders);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [activeReminders]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const notesWithReminder = getNotesWithReminder(notes);
    if (notesWithReminder.length > 0) {
      setActiveReminders(notesWithReminder);
    }
  }, [notes]);

  function getNotesWithReminder(notes) {
    return notes.filter((note) => note.reminder && !note.isReminderShow);
  }

  function handleReminder(reminders) {
    const activeRem = reminders.find((rem) => {
      const now = Date.now();
      const getRemTime = new Date(rem.reminder).getTime();

      return getRemTime <= now;
    });

    setActiveReminder(activeRem);
    setShowNotifyModal(true);
  }
```

Comment: I think you are only clearing the interval and not dismissing the message per se

Answer (score 0):

Message was not dismissing due to if statement which created a memory leak.

solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const notesWithReminder = getNotesWithReminder(notes);
    setActiveReminders(notesWithReminder);
  }, [notes]);
```